# Unable to receive iOS Push Notification from MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

Scenario:

The iOS notifications in SFMC was setup in Jun-Jul when .p12 certificate was in use. During that period we were able to send out notifications. on 14-sep, .p8 was made mandatory for sending out notifications to iOS devices. We updated the certificate likewise.

Following that we haven't been able to send out notifications via SFMC to iOS devices. We've performed following steps to check on the issue.

1. Cross checked certificates, key ID, Bundle ID, Team ID - Everything matches the app store console
2. Sent notifications without using SFMC , directly via APNS - we were able to do so
3. Sent notifications after deleting the contact & reinstalling the app on test devices - Still unable to receive the notifications.

What we've observed is that notifications are being shown as Sent & Delivered from SFMC MobilePush dashboard but we are unable to receive the same.

Will need the forum's help here to get to the root cause of the issue.

Regards,

Comment: Do you have debug information from your app? If they appear to be delivered, you should find something within the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically 1 of 2 things:

1. You have an expired p12, even if it is not currently in use, or
2. You have the it sending to the wrong place debug/production toggle on your administration screen

If you need further assistance, please open a support case through your account representative.